# Device communication with PHP

Tags: php, integration, iot

Using PHP i need to collect data from medical devices like weight machine, thermometer etc in Internet of things concept. If the device have IP address, how can implement connection between device and PHP application? How can collect data from device to PHP application?

Answer (score 2):

Best solution would be, first of all, create some webservice with PHP
And then access this webservice from each device's app.

You will need write software for each device depending on it's OS and capabilities.
It does not matter in which language this software will be written. The only important thing is the fact  this software will communicate with PHP-based webservice to exchange data.

[image]

Comment: I'm using medical devices, not mobile application for connecting with php application. FOr health devices, how its possible?

Comment: Which OS do they have?

Comment: Not sure. I need the concepts/technology used for this. The requirement- I have PHP web application for collecting user medical data. Many devices connected with the application (Blood pressure checking, Thermometer etc). If these devices have IP address, how it can connect to web app and collect user data?

Comment: You need to determine which OS do each device have. Then you need to write software for devices, depending on their OS. Or, maybe devices already have some software pre-install and you just need to configure where will they send data.

Comment: Is it require any applet for data collection?

Comment: This isn't even remotely correct. You can't run an app on a blood pressure monitor or a medical weighing scale. It is possible to gather data with PHP but the exact method will depend on the interface offered by each device. This is most definitely not the way.